# Rendering UI in React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, browser-history

I am still fairly new to ReactJS especially the routing portion of it. I have a couple of questions which I tried many solutions i found on stackoverflow but nothing seems to be helping me:

1. When i start my react project locally, i get `localhost:3000`. What if I want it to be shown as `localhost:3000/extension/`?
2. When i navigate about my project i can render the different pages. However, if i enter the URL directly into the browser, a blank page is rendered. There is no error. I read somewhere saying that my components are not connected to my routes. I am not sure what I need to do to correct it.
3. How can i ensure history is properly being utilized?

routes.js:

```
const RouteList = () => (
<Switch>
  <Route path="/extension/" exact component={withRouter(HomePage)} />
  <Route path="/extension/something" exact component={withRouter(SomethingPage)} />
  <Route component={Error} />
</Switch>
```

);

App.js:

```
class  App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <RouteList />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**--EDIT--**
Added my webpack.config.js

```
const commonConfig = {

  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve('./src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.csv', '.json', '.scss', '.css', '.html']
  },


  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [{ loader: 'eslint-loader', options: { configFile: '.eslintrc' } }]
      },
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{ loader: 'htmlhint-loader', options: { configFile:     '.htmlhintrc' } }],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?    v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        use: [{
          loader: 'html-loader'
        }],
        test: /\.html$/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv)
       }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module) {
        if (module.resource && (/^.*\. 
   (css|less|scss)$/).test(module.resource)) {
          return false;
        }
        return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: __dirname + '/src/images',
      to: ''
    }]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()
  ]
};


const devConfig = {
  entry: {
    main: ['whatwg-fetch', 'core-js/es6', 'react-hot-loader/patch', 'index.js',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true']
  },

  target: 'web',

  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dev_build'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', {loader: 'sass-loader', options: 
{sourceMap: true}}]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?modules']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: [/node_modules/],
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },

 devServer: {
    contentBase: 'src',
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      disableDotRule: true,
      index: 'build/index.html'
    },
    stats: 'minimal',
    overlay: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      },
      '/actuator/**': {
        target: {
          port: 8080
        },
        secure: false
      },
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Please help cause I am not sure what I am doing wrong and i am splitting my brains over this. Thanks.

Comment: you using express or webpack dev server?

Comment: I m using webpack dev server

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Redirect` from `/` to `/extension` if you want that to be the landing page.

```js
const RouteList = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Redirect from='/' to='/extension/'/>
    <Route path="/extension/" exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/extension/something" exact component={SomethingPage} />
    <Route component={Error} />
  </Switch>
);
```

Your app currently only works when visited on `/` because your server will only serve `index.html` for the index route. You can use [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) if you want the `index.html` file to be served instead of any `404` responses.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```